# Jquery script doesn't work so I have to fix the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to disable some fields on a select box, depending on the date and time. I have a WooCommerce website. On my checkout page, I have a select box within a list of specific dates and times when I deliver my product. I would like to prevent visitors from scheduling a delivery for the same day that they place an order. My delivery days are Wed 10:00 - 12:00, Wed 16:00 - 18:00, Sat 10:00 - 12:00, and Sat 12:00 - 14:00.

If a visitor goes to checkout on Wed, I want prevent them from choosing a Wed delivery date (by disabling Wed on the select box), so they can choose only between Sat 10:00 - 12:00 and Sat 12:00 - 14:00. The same is true for Sat.

I am trying to write some jQuery code, but it isn't working. Please, could someone help me to fix this code?

[Checkout page link](https://foodeaty.it/pagamento)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var dmain = new Date(); // for now
    dayis = dmain.getDay();
    houris = dmain.getHours();
    if(dayis == 3 && houris >= 8){
        jQuery("#billing_woocmm9 option[value='mercoledì 10:00 - 12:00']").hide();
        jQuery("#billing_woocmm9 option[value='mercoledì 16:00 - 18:00']").hide();
    } 

    if(dayis == 6 && houris >= 7){ 
        jQuery("#billing_woocmm9 option[value='sabato 10:00 - 12.00']").hide();
        jQuery("#billing_woocmm9 option[value='sabato 12:00 - 14:00']").hide();
    }
```

Your help will be really appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: the code you posted looks like it is invalid. since it is all in one line `// for now...` ends up commenting the rest of the code. There also appears to be a missing `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As that comment says, there is a missing } at the end.  Also, while we're at it, "let" is a better statement than "var" in this situation because "var" will declare the variable globally, whereas "let" will restrict it to this small scope.  Also, the variable names shouldn't really be suffixed by "is" at the end because the == operator does that for you.  Also, I don't think the hide() method can be used on "option" elements, so you should use the remove() method instead.  Also, you might want to check that those values for your options are actually what are used by the site.  Typically, option values are a condensed, non-verbose, abbreviation for what is selected, so that could also be the problem.  Anyway, here's what might work for you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    let now = new Date();
    let day = now.getDay();

    if (day == 3) {
        jQuery("#billing_woocmm9 option[value^='mercoledì']").remove();
    } 
    else if (day == 6) { 
        jQuery("#billing_woocmm9 option[value^='sabato']").remove();
    }

}
```

And here is an alternative method that uses dictionary lookups to avoid a little bit of code repetition:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    let now = new Date();
    let day = now.getDay();

    let day_value_prefixes = {
        3: "mercoled",
        6: "sabato",
    };

    if (day_value_prefixes.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
        jQuery("#billing_woocmm9 option[value^='"+day_value_prefixes[day]+"']").remove();
    }

}
```

Note that in both of these methods, I used "value^=".  The ^= operator here selects values that start with the string, so that we can ignore the ending of the string with all the spaces.  Generally, I like to avoid selecting based on weird characters like that to avoid any problems that might arise from unnoticed double spaces or anything.  Also, along those same lines, I generally don't like to use non-ascii characters like ì internally, in non-user-facing situations, in case there is some weird encoding problem that causes them not to match with selectors or if there is some very similar-looking but technically different character that I would get them confused with.

If you are still having problems, it would be helpful if you would post the relevant html.  It could be that your selector is off somehow - maybe you are using the wrong id for your select tag or something.  You might want to also check that your script is actually being loaded onto the page.